# Connection to MS access 2007 via form using vba

Tags: vba, vbscript, vb6, ms-access-2007

I have created a sample MS access 2007 database and designed a form to retrieve the records of the user , if the username and password entered in the form matches the record.In the button action it redirects to visual basic IDE . May i know how to connect to a ms access database from vba by getting the values from the form, and how to execute SQL query from that.

Comment: VBA questions should not be hypertagged with VB6, VBScript, and anything else starting with VB that you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to work with [Recordsets](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html). To execute SQL that will not return any result use:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL
```